# How to successfully restore nuget packages for entire solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget

Let's say I have fetched fresh solution from the repository, so I get only source code + packages.config, but not packages themselves.

When I open this solution in VS2015 and check the references, those coming from nugets are broken (yellow sign). The property page for reference can look like this:

[image]

Fair enough. I click RMB on solution and select "Manage Nuget Packages for solution", then I select "all repositories" and click "restore" to restore packages.

All nuget packages are restored, I can see them in "installed" list, but references are still broken. And the property page does not change a bit.

To actually restore packages, I have to check "force uninstall" and then manually uninstall and install package after package. Only this restores packages.

Of course this is time consuming, so how to effectively and successfully restore packages with single click?

Comment: Are your project references broken? As in does the uninstall/install fix the hint paths in the project file? If so then a normal restore will not help since it does not fix the hint paths. You would need to use the Package Manager Console and use the `Update-Package -reinstall` command which reinstalls the packages. There is no way to do this with a single click.

Comment: @MattWard, well, in sense they are broken, because this is just a source code, without packages. So the references point to nowhere. So far I noticed that if I create "packages" directory before opening solution, "restore" will work as I wish for the first project of the solution, but the problem remains for the rest (as I described above).

Comment: @MattWard, can you post your comment as an answer? It seems it is VS issue, once it "sees" references are broken it tries to keep it that way. I tested such steps -- before even opening solution in VS, I executed in command line `nuget restore my_solution.sln`, and then I opened solution in VS. It worked!

Comment: I would post your solution as the answer since that worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Matt Ward tip I solved this issue by **first** (literally) running command line and at it executing `nuget restore my_solutions.sln` and only then opening solution in Visual Studio.

Comment: Glad to know that you have resolved this issue. You can mark it as the answer:) astrowalker.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT, I am glad too, yes I will accept it, but SO does not allow it until tomorrow.